# How to Route to wwwroot/index.html on asp.net core 2.2 pages site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got a default web app I've build with vs2019 and asp.net core 2.2.  It sets up just /pages (no MVC controllers and views).  I have a page in my wwwroot (wwwroot/index.html) that I want to have served as default when the user browses to the root of the site.  The following works if I add an extra "/" to my URL but I want it to work without the extra slash.

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).
            AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("", "index.html");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a line of `app.UseDefaultFiles();` will make it :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).
            AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            //options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("", "index.html");   // no need
        }); ;
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();                                     // add this line
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```